OAuth2 Token Fails with "Invalid Audience" (C#)
I am trying to implement server side C# code to get an OAuth2 token and then use it on a subsequent request.  The code I have in place uses a client id, client secret and grant type to issue a call for the token as follows:
internal class AuthToken
{
  [JsonProperty("access_token")]
  public string AccessToken { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("token_type")]
  public string TokenType { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
  public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
  public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

...

 string tokenAddr = @"https://vendor.domain.com/connect/token";
 string grant_type = "client_credentials";   
 string client_id = "vendor-provided-client-id";
 string client_secret = "VENDOR-PROVIDED-SECRET...";

 var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
 {
   {"grant_type", grant_type},
   {"client_id", client_id},
   {"client_secret", client_secret}
 };

 var tokResp = await client.PostAsync(tokenAddr, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));

 var jsonContent = await tokResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

 AuthToken tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthToken>(jsonContent);


The resulting 'AuthToken' class gets populated with what appears to be a completely valid token, token type, expiration, and refresh option.
I pass this along on the subsequent request:
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {tok.AccessToken}");

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);


The response will always contain a 401 ("unauthorized") and upon inspecting the headers, there is an error message: "invalid Audience"
NOW... if I use Postman to generate a token using grant type "Authorization Code (with PKCE)" such that the user is prompted for their credentials:

... the token I get back from THAT call in Postman can be dropped into the request above, and it works. (!)  So the request is formulated properly, but there is something wrong with the token I'm getting back.
I cannot use the grant type "Authorization Code (with PKCE)" in MY code because this needs to be fully automated.  AND... if I attempt to use "client_credentials" grant type with client id and client secret in Postman, that ALSO generates a token that results in a 401 / Invalid Auidience.
So...
The first question is :  Why would the auth token returned using 'client_credentials' grant type fail with "invalid Audience"?
The second question is : How can I fix this?  What am I missing here?

Why don't you decode the token and search for aud claim. Just paste it in https://jwt.io/ .  Which identity provider do you use? You have to configure token claims.

@andrija : It turns out this was all related to the "scope" field being incorrect.  Once that value was set properly, it all works perfectly.   (Dodgy documentation on the vendors part).... but thanks for your response.
